# Instantiate an variable with a methods return object

Tags: php, dom, object, methods

I have been searching for hours but I can't seem to understand why this does not work. Here is the code

My goal is to have a different method to load the XML document, and another one to print and manage that document.

```
class ...

//Fetch and print xml document
    function fetchFromXMLDocument($XMLDocName) {
        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmlDoc->load($XMLDocName);
        return $xmlDoc;

    }
```

Here I want do add the value of the `fetchFromXMLDocument()` to my `$he` variable.
   but it does not seem to be working?

```
function printXml($XMLDocName) {
   //this seems not to be right??       
    $he = fetchFromXMLDocument($XMLDocName);

    //after that this is what I want to do..
    // $items = $he->getElementsByTagName("item");
         ...
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea on why that might be?

Comment: Can you explain what does not seem to be working?

Comment: @jprofitt It does not seem to instiate that object `xmlDoc` to my variable `$he`. Maybe this makes no sense in PHP, maybe I'm wrong with this seems I have done this on java??

Comment: What does `var_dump($he)` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem is that function `fetchFromXMLDocument();` is inside a class.

If the method you are accessing it from `printXML`, is within the same class then you should access it using `$this` operator.

```
function printXml($XMLDocName) {    
     $he = $this -> fetchFromXMLDocument($XMLDocName);
     ...
}
```

**However**, If the method you are accessing it from `printXML`, is outside. Then first you have to create and object of the class and access it.

```
function printXml($XMLDocName) {    
     $obj = new yourxmlclassname();
     $he = $obj -> fetchFromXMLDocument($XMLDocName);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$xmlDoc` is a DomDocument object. You probably want:

```
$he = $xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

Comment: but `$he` is in a different method that `$xmlDoc` What I need is to use the content of the `$xmlDoc` in another method than the one that it is in?

Comment: Oh, I see...you want to still use it as a DomDocument object, not get the XML output of it. `return`ing like you are should give that to you. Are you sure that the value being returned is a valid object? (that the file was imported successfully?)

Comment: hey thank you for you feedback. The problem was that I did not use `$this` since I was doing that inside a class..

Answer (score 0):

if it's in a class, wouldn't you have to do

```
$he = $this->fetchFromXMLDocument($XMLDocName)
```

Comment: try it. You never said what about it wasn't working, so that really didn't give us much to work with.  It would be helpful if you add error reporting and let us know what the errors are.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem :)